# Function noT updating when I flash fill

Tags: excel

I am trying to edit a column in a worksheet, but when I try to flash fill it does not update accordingly.
I tried a very basic function =LEN(A1) to see what was happening and =SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","") to omit unnecessary spaces, this is what I am getting:

DW80R9950UT/AA  DW80R9950UT/AA  14

DW80R9950UG/AA  DW80R9950UT/AA  14

SKK-BB  DW80R9950UT/AA  14

SKK-8K  DW80R9950UT/AA  14

The document was sent as a binary worksheet. I tried working it in that format and tried to save as .xlsx
Is it an issue with the file or flash fill format or something else?

Comment: maybe your "spaces" are not acutal spaces but non breaking spaces.

Comment: I tried =TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(160), " ")) to eliminate non breaking spaces, but I still run into the same flash fill problem. The flash fill duplicates the value of first cell, but if I move up down the column I see function tab updating the cell location.

Comment: are your calcs set to manual?  try hiting F9

Comment: That was it! Thank you!